# Netty Multiple Clients, disconnecting one affects all

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, netty

I am working on a java server-client based app and using Netty (4.0.27.Final) for TCP socket connections. I have facing an issue with client side.

In client I use one BootStrap, one NioEventLoopGroup for multiple clients (100+ concurrent clients) and just call the following for each new client connection.

```
b.handler(new MyConnectionInitializer());
b.connect(IP, PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
```

Now after doing work each client calls `ctx.disconnect()`. After calling it, all the clients receive ChannelInactive and connection to server for all the clients get disconnect. While I just want that only the client for which `ctx.disconnect` is called should be disconnect.

Should I call some other function instead of `ctx.disconnect()`?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Will ctx.deregister be any help here?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `close()` instead of `disconnect()`. As far as I understand `disconnect()` actually closes the connection (and with it all other channels that might still be open) while `close()` only closes the current channel.

Please someone correct me if I wrote something wrong.